# How to keep repeatable html background-image size unchanged when browser is zoomed?

Tags: html, css

I have repeatable background-image set to html element:

```
html {
  background-image: url("/url-to-image.png");
  background-repeat: round;
}
```

I'm writing media queries for high resolution displays to make elements not blury when browser window is automatically scaled.

Is there a way to make html background-image to be the same size, even when browser window is zoomed?

Comment: try "background-attachment: fixed;"      .... http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Comment: Have you tried adding a fixed size to the image? `background-size: 200px 200px;`

Comment: Alexis Peters - this property is for making background not scrollable, and when it is set, it is still zoomed if browser is zoomed.

Comment: ScarletMerlin - thanks! I just needed to decrease the background-image size for media queries and it worked!